# ng-click not working when button is pushed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get a function to execute when a button is clicked...

Here is my button:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<div ng-controller="convertController">
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert()">
        Convert
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter',['ionic']);
myApp.controller('convertController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.convert = function(){
       alert("convert");
    }                            
}]);
```

Why is the function not being called when I click the button?

Comment: is the button within the scope of where the app is defined?

Comment: Try to provide a plunker. Maybe this will clear up your question right away or we can at least see the whole segment and don't have to guess :)

Comment: check you have the appropriate `ng-app` and `ng-controller` .

Comment: And `$scope` as parameter in your controller function

Comment: I added more for you to see..

Comment: which version of angularJS do you use ? and are you sure that you included the js file in the right position? does other stuff in your project work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is fine, it should work as you can see in the snippet below that is a copy paste of your code (except for the `ionic` dependency).

The problem probably comes from elsewhere. Please check your console for any error, Angular probably couldn't initiate for another reason (for instance cannot resolve the ionic dependency?).

How to see errors [using Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

How to see errors [using Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('starter',[]);
myApp.controller('convertController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.convert = function(){
       alert("convert");
    }                            
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="starter">

<div ng-controller="convertController">
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert()">
        Convert
    </button>
</div>
</body>
```